# Getting an error when trying to insert picture directory into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form which is filed out by the user and a php script to insert the inputs into my table, however it keeps returning an error, I am able to insert all of the values other than the picture directory into the table.

These are my table values:

```
Field              Type             Null    
Name               Text             No
Picture            varchar(30)      No
Date               date             No
Price              int(11)          No
```

This is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>

    </head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="addEvent.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
    Enter the Name of the Event:
      <input type="text" name ="Name"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    Picture:
      <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000" />
      <input type="file" name="Photo" />
    </p>
    <p>
    Date:
      <input type="date" name="Date"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    Price
      <input type="number" name="Price"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" title="Add data to the Database" value="Add   Event"/>
<br/>
<br/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the script that I am using to insert the files into the database with the username and password of the database remove ofc.

```
<?php


$target = "public_html/events/Pictures";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);


$name=$_POST['Name'];
$Picture=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$Date=$_POST['Date'];
$Price=$_POST['Price'];



 mysql_connect("Host", "User", "pass") or      die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error()) ;


mysql_query("INSERT INTO Events (Name,Picture,Date,Price)
VALUES ('$name', '$Picture', '$Date', '$Price')") ;


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{


echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and     your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {


echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

The script is currently returning the error "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."

Can anyone see what the problem is? 
The directory that I am trying to upload into is public_html/Events/Pictures

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Edit:
Changed the Script and now I am getting a new error.

```
<?php


$target = "public_html/events/Pictures/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['Photo']['name']);


$name=$_POST['Name'];
$Picture=($_FILES['Photo']['name']);
$Date=$_POST['Date'];
$Price=$_POST['Price'];



 mysql_connect("mysql.hostinger.co.uk", "u219259269_admin", "password") or     die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("u219259269_event") or die(mysql_error()) ;


mysql_query("INSERT INTO Events (Name,Picture,Date,Price)
VALUES ('$name', '$Picture', '$Date', '$Price')") ;


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{


echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
  }
    else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Warning: move_uploaded_file(public_html/events/Pictures/Test.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u219259269/public_html/events/addEvent.php on line 31

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/php79Pc7Q' to 'public_html/events/Pictures/Test.jpg' in /home/u219259269/public_html/events/addEvent.php on line 31
Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.

Comment: http://php.net/move_uploaded_file "If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued."

Comment: Delete the comments :)

Comment: your question is confusing. Are you not able to save picture name in database or you are not able to upload or save file in targeted directory? you should use ini_set('display_errors', 1); and check for error. hope that might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly, the question happens because :

1) the path "public_html/Events/Pictures" not exist

2) The PHP script has no permission to write the file into the directory.

So you can check your public_html/Events/Pictures at first.

Comment: Thanks for the help I found the full directory and put that in instead and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$Picture=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

This is case sensitive so you either need to use "Photo" for both or "photo" for both

```
<input type="file" name="Photo" />
```

Comment: I changed what you said and then was getting a directory error but that is notw fixed, thanks for the help